# Can I compute the interior product of a function with respect to a vector field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry

I was doing my homework for my geometric methods in diffeq course, and we were asked to prove the following:

> If we are on an euclidean space $(E,g)$ , and $f\in C^\infty(E)$. We define $D=grad f$, show that $D(f)=i_Ddf\geq0$.

The inequality is trivial since $D$ is the vector field such that $i_D g =df$. Thus $i_D df= g(D,D)\geq 0$ because $g$ is euclidean. The problem arises with showing that  $Df=i_D df$. I thought of doing it using Cartan's formula, considering that the Lie derivative of D for functions is just applying the vector field to the function, so $Df=D^Lf=(i_D\circ d + d\circ i_D)f$. But i dont know if it makes any sense applying $i_D$ to a function. I thought it might be zero or a constant because the interior product $i_D$ reduces in one the order of the tensors in the exterior algebra, and in some sort of sense the tensors of order -1 might be just the constants since tensors of order 0 are the functions.

If anyone knows another way of solving this problem please tell me too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $i_D$ is a differential operator with degree $-1$: it sends $\Omega^k(E)$ to $\Omega^{k-1}(E)$. As $f \in \Omega^0(E)$, $i_Df$ is a $-1$-form, that is, the null form $0$. But you can outpass this difficulty noticing that by definition, if $X$ is a vector field and $f$ a function, $X\cdot f = df(X)$, that is, $i_X(df)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me!